# how to prompt sheet selection in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

When a workbook has many sheets such as 100, you can activate the sheet quickly by right-clicking the arrows on the bottom left and then a prompts shows up by lets you choose which sheet you want to select. However, I want to be able to reach this prompt without clicking and using just the keyboard. So I want to create a simple macro where I can quickly pull up this prompt by assigning to something like ctrl+g. However, I do not know how to do this in vba.

Comment: How do you want the user to select the sheet? By name?

Answer (score 1):

Build your replica Activate form: Insert a userform into your project. Set its caption to "Activate". Add a label to it that says "Activate:". Add a Listbox and two buttons. Label one button Ok and the other Cancel.

In the UserForm_Initialize sub of the userform, Loop through the names of your sheets and add them to the listbox....something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet

    For Each oSheet In Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem oSheet.Name
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets(ListBox1.Text).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Now in the ThisWorkbook section of the VBA Project, add a sub to show your userform:

```
Private Sub ShowActivateForm()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Go back to Excel and click the Macros button on the developer tab. You should see a macro named ShowActivateForm. Select it and click Options to assign it your desired hotkey.

Comment: Nice installation instructions!